# Custom sorting on elasticsearch contiguous results by attribute

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I've been checking the internet for an Elasticsearch documentation or an example to solve my problem on manipulating query results but no luck so far. Here's the problem i want to solve.

I want to avoid product results having contiguous merchant_id. I need to move a document in between products that have the same merchant_id. For more visual understanding on my question, here's an example result and the expected result i need.

Original ES result:

```
{ "merchant_id": 1, "product_name": "Product 1" },
{ "merchant_id": 1, "product_name": "Product 2" },
{ "merchant_id": 1, "product_name": "Product 3" },
{ "merchant_id": 2, "product_name": "Product 4" },
{ "merchant_id": 2, "product_name": "Product 5" },
{ "merchant_id": 2, "product_name": "Product 6" }
```

Expected ES result:

```
{ "merchant_id": 1, "product_name": "Product 1" },
{ "merchant_id": 2, "product_name": "Product 4" },
{ "merchant_id": 1, "product_name": "Product 2" },
{ "merchant_id": 2, "product_name": "Product 5" },
{ "merchant_id": 1, "product_name": "Product 3" },
{ "merchant_id": 2, "product_name": "Product 6" }
```

Comment: This looks quite random. What's the reason for the 2nd row not being switched with, say, the 4th row in your expected result? It's also merchant2... So please add some sort of reasoning to your question because otherwise it's just too custom & too random. What's the use case? It may be approached differently.

Comment: Yeah it looks too custom & too random when I first saw this requirement. Here's the use case.

These results are being displayed in a product listing page, let's say 30 products per page. Now, we need to avoid displaying all 30 products in a page that only belongs to a single merchant because we also want to showcase other products from other merchants to be fair. Right now, the current results that we are getting are only sorted by score. I'm not quite sure how to handle this additional custom sorting requirement.

Comment: OK I see. What are they sorted by then? If you randomize the order afterwards, you'd lose the underlying sort... So why not retrieve from ES what you usually would and randomize it in the frontend?

Answer (score 0):

The best is to randomize the result  :

```
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        //your query
      },
      "functions": [
        {
          "random_score": {}
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```